# index.php being used instead of archive.php for blog posts

Tags: php, wordpress, post, woocommerce, archive

**Summary:**

In a WordPress WooCommerce site posts are defaulting to using index.php for the template instead of archive.php

My understanding of the hierarchy is that if archive.php exists it should be used by posts instead of index.php. I want it to work that way but index.php is being used by the site.

**Background:**

I inherited the code base from another developer. Their version of the site is still being hosted and I can see that the archive pages ARE working correctly on their hosted version of the site.

I was given a dump of the files and database. When I set it up locally I see the archive pages are broken. I've determined that its because the wrong template is being applied (index is being used instead of archive). I have not made any changes from what was given to me. It should be an identical code base and *nearly* identical database. (database changed to find/replace the base url to match my local).

**Attempted steps so far:**

1. Went to Settings -> Permalinks and switched to other structures. No change in behavior so I set it back to numeric which is what it was to start.
2. Saw a suggestion in an old thread to add theme support for WooCommerce. No effect.
3. Created a custom template that matches the old archive.php and set each post to use the custom template. This works BUT its not ideal because the content creators would have to set the template for each new post. This is my backup option if I can't get archive.php to be recognized like its should.

Any troubleshooting advice is appreciated. Thank you!